# Are questions about safety-equipment testing off-topic?

Tags: discussion

A question I had asked about [checking respirators](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/231809/4505) awhile back was recently closed as "off-topic". From my understanding, it would fall under tools & best practices for home improvement tasks, which would make it on-topic. Would not safety equipment &  testing it both be topics for this site? Could I get a more detailed reason why it might be considered off-topic (with an eye toward flagging for reopening if it could be edited to be on-topic)?

As time went on, the question got deleted automatically, so some here might not be able to read it in order to evaluate it. For now, I've reproduced the content below for such users so as to allow for review & discussion.

> As part of using a reusable respirator (such as a 3M 6000, 6500 or 7500 series), one is supposed to check leakage around the seal with the face by blocking the exhalation valve and exhaling (a positive pressure seal check). When performing this check, is any amount of air leakage through an intake valve acceptable? If so, about how much?

Comment: It looks as if that question is now deleted.

Comment: @computercarguy: It got deleted automatically by the Community bot. I've added the content to this question so it can be reviewed.

Comment: I don't see a problem with the question, as stated here, although it might not explicitly be allowed or it may be considered as looking for "highly opinionated" answers. IDK about 3M masks, but in the US Army using gas masks, we opened the exhaust to blow out (clear) air trapped by the mask, then close the intake valve while inhaling to seal the mask to our faces. Granted, this is a different use mask. We were more worried about negative pressure than positive pressure, but the negative pressure seal generally took care of positive pressure leaks, too.